# How to return HTTP 404 instead of HTTP 204 response code for null values in jersey

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I have a Jersey REST API that returns 204 No content instead of 404 when the entity to be returned back is `null`.

To address this issue, I'm currently planning to throw an exception within the resource method so that it could force Jersey to return 404 like below.

```
if (feature == null) throw new WebApplicationException(404);
```

But I have various REST URIs that suffer from the same problem. Is there a way to address all of them without touching each and every resource method?

My resource methods look like this:

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.example.webapi.domain.Feature;
import com.example.webapi.service.FeatureService;

@Component
@Path("features")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class FeatureResource {

    @Autowired
    private FeatureService featureService;

    @GET
    public List<Feature> getFeatures() {
        return featureService.listAllFeatures();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("{featureCode}")
    public Feature getFeature(@PathParam("featureCode") Integer featuresCode) {
        return featureService.findFeatureByFeatureCode(featuresCode);
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response addFeature(Feature feature, @Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
        Integer id = (Integer) featureService.createFeature(feature);
        return Response.created(uriInfo.getAbsolutePathBuilder().path(id.toString()).build()).entity(feature).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can send your own response code through the Response object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can  implement ContainerResponseFilter and customise the response based on your requirement.

ex:

```
@Provider
public class LoggingResponseFilter
    implements ContainerResponseFilter {

private static final Logger logger =      LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingResponseFilter.class);

public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext,
        ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {
    String method = requestContext.getMethod();

    logger.debug("Requesting " + method + " for path " + requestContext.getUriInfo().getPath());
    Object entity = responseContext.getEntity();
    if (entity != null) {
        logger.debug("Response " + new ObjectMapper().writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(entity));
    }
}
```

}

Customize the above code and implement your business logic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Request or Response filters depends on what you want to check for null.

check the docs [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html)