# What are http codes when returning possibly null Uni or empty Multi in reasteasy?

Tags: resteasy, quarkus, mutiny

Where can I find docs for the http codes when returning a possibly null or empty `Uni`/`Multi`?

I have found out that returning a possibly null Uni returns http status 204 (no content) when using a get request such as /users/123. Shouldn't this return 404? How would I check the Uni or Multi before returning results? I'm using `resteasy`

Comment: You can control the Response code by returning `Response` in your JAX-RS methods instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't seem to find it now, but this is standard JAX-RS behavior (of which RESTEasy is an implementation).

Comment: My background is in `vertx`, so reasteasy was slightly new, but it seems that's how it works based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37327582/how-to-return-http-404-instead-of-http-204-response-code-for-null-values-in-jers. will have to write a filter or return throw a `WebApplicationException(404)`